# How to fill a listview with an edit text?

Tags: android, listview, sdk, adapter

i have to activities:
activity 1 with twoo edit text and
activity 2 with a list view.
Everytime i fill the forms in activity1 and press the button "send" i want that all i have wrote in the two edit texts go in one row of the list view of activity 2.
I have tried and it is the result but i don't know how i have to continue:
this is the code of activity1 when the button is pressed:

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Button Send Report Clicked......");


                                      object=object.getText().toString();
            description = editDescription.getText().toString();

            getCoordinates();
            Intent i=new Intent(FirstReporting.this, MyList.class);
            i.putExtra("object", object);
            i.putExtra("description", description);

            startActivity(i);               
        }
    });
```

this is the code of activity2:

```
arrayAdapterListReports arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterListReports(this, R.layout.item_list_reports, listReports);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

and then?

Answer (score 1):

In that other activity you can do this to get the values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String objStr = extras.getString("object");
    String descStr = extras.getString("description");
    // Do what you want with these now ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) guide.

In your second Activity, you can retrieve the Intent used to start Activity2 using `getIntent()`.

You can then use that [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) object to get your data like so:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
String obj = extras.getString("object");
String desc = extras.getString("description");
```

Comment: You didn't really provide any information on what kind of `ListAdapter` you are using. Judging from the name of the class, I'm going to assume it is an `ArrayAdapter` of some sort, so you would use  [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)'s `add()` method.